# How to disable Touchscreen on Linux Machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchscreen

Issue with ghost touch.
Unable to Open any application or work properly.

**Fixed:**
We will need the below script and application, but before that I know you will be facing the ghost touch and doing the below will be impossible.

Hence i would recommend to use the vga/hdmi cable and output your laptop screen on a different monitor. It will not give that issue on the separate monitor.

Once you are ready to type and work. Lets get the below done..

1. First create a script and name it anything <disable_touchscreen.sh>(in my case), to fetch the touchscreen id.

**Script**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the touchscreen information
test=$(xinput --list | grep -i touchscreen)

# Extract the ID from the touchscreen information
touchscreen_id=$(echo "$test" | awk -F 'id=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')

# Disable the touchscreen using the extracted ID
xinput disable "$touchscreen_id"

#echo "Disabled Touchscreen with ID: $touchscreen_id"
```

2. (Optional) Download a png of a touchscreen // keep both the script and png in same location
3. create file name app_script.desktop // to create the desktop application
4. Enter the below content to a file named anything <app_script.desktop>(in my case), specifing the path of the script and path of the image and modify the name etc. Note: Keep the terminal=True, it will allow the terminal to open and execute.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=/home/kishor/Pictures/touchscreen_disable/disable_touchscreen.sh
Name=Disable_Touch
Comment=Disabling touchscreen on startup
Icon=/home/kishor/Pictures/touchscreen_disable/touch.png
```

5. Once the content is saved with updated entries.
6. move/copy the app_script.desktop file to the location "~/.local/share/applications"
7. make the script executable by chmod:
   `chmod +x app_script.desktop`
8. You should see the application now.
9. To run the script when the os boots up, for that you can install "gnome tweaks"
10. Once gnome tweaks is installed, launch it from terminal as below:
    `gnome-tweaks`
11. Now Under Startup Application, click on + button to add application.
12. Search with the name of the application. In our case its: "Disable Touch"
13. Close the gnome-tweaks and next time when ever you boot the OS. It will get the id and disable it and give it to you for a hustle free workflow to begin.

Happy Hacking..

Let me know if you have any other ways to fix this other than my fix.

Comment: Is this a question and an answer at the same time? It's ok to answer your own question, but that should be in an actual answer, not in the question. stackoverflow is very strict about separating questions and answers, see the [tour]. Also keep in mind that stackoverflow is for programming questions, and Linux configuration and tool use fits usually better on [unix.se] or https://superuser.com